# HTML: Input Button frozen on busy webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

During times when a website is experiencing a lot of traffic, sometimes the functionality of a lot of the form buttons do not work on the web page.  For example here is the code for the web pages "add to cart" button...

```
<fieldset id="add-remove-buttons">
   <input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="add to cart">
   <a href="/shop" class="button continue">keep shopping</a>
</fieldset>

<script id="cart-controls-add" type="text/x-nano-tmpl">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/shop/170325/add" class="add" data-remote="true" id="cart-addf" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
       <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
       <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="YzR1rCDbfkdbY9M7Fvlx61/adGM9rO51uo6kFFBtdnk=" /></div>
    <fieldset>
      <input id="size" name="size" type="hidden" value="40401" />
      <a href="/shop/accessories/ysw1o8v0k" class="next">next accessory &gt;</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="add-remove-buttons">
       <input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="add to cart" />
       <a href="/shop" class="button continue">keep shopping</a>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</script>
```

Is this just something that is an issue on the server side that cannot be mitigated on client-side? I was thinking about using a while loop to keep submitting input function until it succeeds but sometimes it never succeeds. Or might it be better to do a site refresh, try again, if not, then refresh and try again, repeat?  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this your website? If you have access to the server logs, you might be able to figure out where the bottleneck is and whether or not you will be able to mitigate it without upgrading your hardware. (This doesn't sound like a client-side issue.)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it is not my website... so i don't have access to it. I assumed it was just a server side issue but I was wondering if there was a better way for me to mitigate client side.

Comment: I'm afraid not, other than browsing at 3 AM...

Comment: That's what I figured...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the request is timing out. Rather than resubmitting, (which just adds to the load,) if you change this to a JavaScript AJAX call, you can set a timeout on the client side. Depending on what your server is, you can look at the timeout settings on the server-side. I'd put up a visual indication like a spinner until you get a success or failure back from an AJAX call.